# How to bypass local DNS cache using socket api getaddrinfo?

Tags: c++, linux, dns

I know it can be done using win API DnsQuery. But is there a way to do the same thing on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) there is no way to force `getaddrinfo` to bypass any cache and `/etc/gai.conf` doesn't let you do that either. You might get away with using a custom resolver such as [adns](http://www.gnu.org/software/adns/).

---

Side note: to clarify the mention about DnsQuery, the OP was likely talking about [DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc982162)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I found that Linux doesn't have a OS-level cache by default. So problem solved...